# Offsets don't work when using 'row-fluid' in Twitter's Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap-Twitter, and whenever I try to use fluid rows, offsets on spans don't work. Here's some code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="well span4 offset4">
            Content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And all that's happening is that the well is **not offsetting** by 4 spaces. I Googled it, but could't find a clear answer. Does anybody have a fix?

Comment: I'd just like to note that it probably isn't a good idea to mix the grid's `span` classes with `well` or other classes meant for content.  Doing so will inevitably blow out your grid, as many content classes add padding and margins of their own, which both affect the total outer width of the element.  If you had 3 `.span4.well` divs in a single 12-column row, they wouldn't fit on the screen.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2394) has been raised over at Github and according to the Bootstrap developers a fix will come with time, so i guess in the meantime you mainly have to rely on hacks. Two ways you can go about it is to add the `.offset` to the `.row-fluid` class (if that works out for you) or add the `.offset` class of your choice to your stylesheet and declare it with the `!important` property, like so:

```
.offset4 {
    margin-left: 340px !important;
}
```

Comment: but that isn't fluid! personally, I like the solution posted by RussellUresti, below (with the exception of the usage of :not(), which appears to be required, unfortunately).

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap now supports this:

> As of 2.1.0-wip, .offset* classes will now work with the fluid grid system

https://twitter.com/twbootstrap/status/215649222224134144

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use the `!important` property on the existing offset class, as it defines a pixel value and the whole point of using fluid is to use percentages.

Here's a formula that I came up with for creating your own offset for fluid rows.

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
  .row-fluid .offset#{$i} {
    margin-left: (6.382978723% * $i) + (2.127659574% * $i);
    *margin-left: (6.329787233638298% * $i) + (2.0744680846382977% * $i);
  }
}
```

So, let me explain what you're seeing here. This is a for loop using SCSS, used to write the offset1 - offset12 classes. This is only for a single media query, as you'll have to define define it 3 times (since the widths and offsets are changed in 3 separate media queries in the twitter bootstrap code). The basic principle is this:

```
margin-left = (width_of_span1 * x) + (margin-left_of_row-fluid_span* * x)
```

The value of `x` is equal to the number of columns you wish to offset, so, for `.offset1` you would use `1` as the value of `x`. For `.offset12` you would use `12` as the value of `x`.

You will also need to adjust one more style, as twitter bootstrap puts a `margin-left: 0` on the `:first-child` element within the `.row-fluid` container. Now, the easiest way is to just add the `!important` attribute to your newly declared `.row-fluid .offset*` classes. You might also be able to do adjust their `:first-child` selector so that it reads:

`.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child:not([class*=offset])`

This would only apply the `margin-left: 0` if the `.span*` element did NOT have any of the `.offset*` classes as well. Though, browser support for that type of thing is probably pretty limited.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4">
    Content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solution creates empty rows when everything collapses into one item per row (on narrow screens).

Comment: This can be combined with `.hidden-phone` utility class to overcome empty rows as Marius pointed out